# Sort returning different results in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

```
function sort(type) {
    $("#parentDiv").empty();
    $.getJSON("raw_data.json", ({ Search }) => {   
        Search.sort((a, b) => a[type] > b[type]);
        console.log(`Sorted by: ${type}`);
        ...code
```

Different results are shown in different browsers, but the correct one is showing in firefox devoloper edition and wrong results are shown in chrome browser.

Comment: Sort functions should return -1, 0, or 1 -- not true or false. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: What are the right results? What are the wrong results? Why isn't your sort function returning -1, 0, or 1?

Comment: Why the braces around Search? `({ Search })`

Comment: @Wainage It's a feature of ES6 called [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Pulling_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) :)

Comment: @4castle Thanks boss. Learn something every day.

Answer (score 0):

The sort function should return a number,

a number less than 0 will move element A to a lower index than B

a number greater than 0 will move element B  to a lower index than A

if the number is zero it will leave the elements at the same place.

More about the sort function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: whats wrong in this?
function sort(type) {
   $("#parentDiv").empty();
    $.getJSON("raw_data.json", ({ Search }) => {   
        function Sear(a, b) {
  return (a[Search.type] < b[Search.type]) ? -1 : (a[Search.type] > b[Search.type]) ? 1 : 0;};
        console.log(`Sorted by: ${type}`);
  console.log("movies are displayed!!");
  var i;