# variable(search) not defined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

```
function sort(type) {
    $("#parentDiv").empty();
    $.getJSON("raw_data.json", ({ Search }));

    function Sear(a, b) {
        return (a[Search.type] < b[Search.type]) ? -1 : (a[Search.type] > b[Search.type]) ? 1 : 0;
    };
}
```

My `raw_data.json` will be [here](http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=minions&y=2015&plot=full&r=json).

Though I've declared search. It is occuring an error:

> search is not defined.

Comment: Can you show the code where you defined `Search`? Also, to get the response from the AJAX request, why did you stop using a callback like your [previous code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37578249/5743988)?

Comment: There are so many things wrong here, I don't even know where to begin...

Comment: function sort(type) {
   $("#parentDiv").empty();
    $.getJSON("raw_data.json", ({ Search }) => {   
        Search.sort((a, b) => a[type] > b[type]);
        console.log(`Sorted by: ${type}`);
  console.log("movies are displayed!!");
  var i;
 ...code

Comment: Search is defined in raw_data.json in which the data is taken from this url http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Batman&page=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sort(type) {
  $("#parentDiv").empty();
$.getJSON("raw_data.json", ({ Search }) => {   
    Search.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a[type]<b[type]){return -1;}
     else if(a[type]>b[type]){
    return 1;
    }
    else {
    return 0;
    }
    });
    console.log(`Sorted by: ${type}`);
    console.log("movies are displayed!!");
    var i;
   ... code
```